# PostGIS 3D buffer along an axis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, sfcgal, extrude

##### TL;DR

In PostGIS, I'm searching the most efficient way to compute a 3D geometry extruded along an arbitrary axis given as a LineString Z in space (each coordinate varies along the axis).

##### Explanation

According to the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html):

> The ST_Buffer function ignores the Z dimension. It always gives a 2D result even when used on a 3D geometry.

So I was having a glimpse at the [SFCGAL extension](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/reference_sfcgal.html) and I found [`ST_Extrude`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extrude.html). But the doc is not much verbose on what exactly the 3 parameters x,y and z are. One can easily guess they are the direction along the 3 axes of an orthogonal reference frame, probably the one of the geometry. There is also a function called [`CG_Extrude`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/CG_Extrude.html) with apparently the same signature (why then the two different functions?).

But with such function, one cannot extrude a 3D geometry along an arbitrary axis in 3D space along which each coordinate varies.

Use cases are for example, constructing a flight corridor having a rectangular cross-section around a flight line (see  figure 1), or a pipe having a circular cross-section around its axis.

[image]

Figure 1: *A flight corridor.*
Image source: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/analyzing-threats-to-3d-flight-paths-and-corridors.htm

The approach I imagine is to discretise the line into individual straight segments, and computing, for each segment, the (x,y,z) triplet to then extrude along that segment, before extruding with a given shape perpendicular to that segment.

But I don't know how to make a proper "join" between two segments that have an angle (elbow). For example, by using something similar to the join style parameters in the equivalent 2-dimensional [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) function.

I'm currently not considering curved lines for simplicity because this would involve modeling a torus-like 3D structure.

All in all, I find this approach a little cumbersome and probably not very efficient.

Hence my question; what would be the most *efficient* way to compute such 3D geometry along an arbitrary axis (LineString Z having bends) in PostGIS?

Comment: If the Z is static along the LineString; on PostGIS >= 3.1 trivially `ST_Extrude(ST_Force3DZ(ST_Buffer(<line_Z>), <static_Z_minus_half_target_extrusion_height>), 0, 0, <half_target_extrusion_height)`. If you have dynamic Z the most efficient way would be to write a slim `'plpgsql'` function that applyies vector translations at each vertex in all dimensions, and then stitches them into faces.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision: each coordinate of the axis can vary in space. Including the Z coordinate, as in a flight path during take-off. But we can consider each individual segment to be straight.